# What is wrong with this simple SwiftUI example?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I’ve got this simple SwiftUI app and it doesn’t behave as expected.

The app consists of a view simply displaying some hello message and a toolbar button triggering the presentation of a sheet. Prior to the presentation a `@State` property (`tmpEvent`) is set to the desired value.

When the sheet is displayed for the *first* time it doesn’t show the newly assigned value but the initialisation value. On all subsequent presentations of the sheet it works as expected.

What am I missing here?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var presentingSheet = false
  @State private var tmpEvent = Event(desc: "default Event")
  @State private var counter = 0
  
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Text("Hello Test App")
      }
      .toolbar {
        Button(action: showSheet) {
          Label("Open sheet", systemImage: "plus")
        }
      }
      .sheet(
        isPresented: $presentingSheet,
        onDismiss: { tmpEvent = Event(desc: "onDismiss Event") }
      ) {
        NavigationView {
          VStack {
            Text("event: \(tmpEvent.desc)")
          }
          .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
          .navigationTitle(tmpEvent.desc)
          .toolbar {
            Button(action: { presentingSheet = false }) {
              Label("Close", systemImage: "xmark")
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  private func showSheet() {
    counter += 1
    tmpEvent = Event(desc: "new Event \(counter)")
    presentingSheet = true
  }
}
```

### Update: here is the `Event` struct

```swift
struct Event {
  var desc: String
}
```

If you want to play with the example you can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/raywo/SwiftTestApp/).

Comment: Event extends from : ObservableObject?

Comment: No. It is a simple struct.

Comment: use the `sheet` with `item` in it

Comment: onDismiss is fired when the sheet is closed so that is why you don’t see it the first time you open the sheet

Comment: If you change Event by a simple string it works? Maybe you need a $tmpEvent on assigning the value on it. $tmpEvent = Event(desc: "new Event \(counter)"

Comment: Thanks @lorem-ipsum for the heads up! This answered my question perfectly. Actually this leads me to exactly where I want to be with the real app I am developing right now.